# How to use backend permissions in frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest, web-applications, permissions

I have a web application using Rails as backend and AngularJS as frontend and it has a rather complicated permission system that must hide/show buttons in the frontend accordingly.

For example, imagine something like ebay, if I created a product, I can edit, delete, etc.. but somebody can share a product with me and I can also edit, but not delete. So the permission is calculated by resource, and not using roles.

I thought adding a "permissions" attribute to each json object, something like:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "product 1",
    permissions: {
        canEdit: true,
        canDelete: false
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "product 2",
    permissions: {
        canEdit: true,
        canDelete: true
    }
}]
```

Is there any best practice to send each resource permissions to the frontend?

Just to be clear, this permissions are only used to **show/hide** buttons, the backend still blocks this resources even if the person changes the values in the frontend

Comment: You shouldn't handle permissions like this on the front end as someone could easily modify it...

Comment: this permissions are only used to show/hide buttons, changing it will not allow the person to perform any actions

Answer (score 0):

As the logic to figure out what a user can do with each item is determined on the server side, I reckon it's redundant to pass on the permissions associated with these items to client-side, unless additional processing is done on client-side based on user's interaction. 
In your case, maybe you can just return different collections of objects, say an editable list and a read-only list to the client-side, based on permissions associated and then render actions based on which collection the item belongs to?

Comment: Curious to know if this helped?

Comment: An endpoint can receive the user identificacion, check it's permissions and response with a group of keys with boolean values related to all the show/hide components for and specific frontend (in this case an Angular one).